# A word for "1-dimensional variable"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is there any noun or adjective (other than 1-manifold) that can reasonably be used for a variable that is constrained to a 1-dimensional space?

I would want the following examples to qualify:

1. A variable in $\mathbb{R}$
2. A variable modeling *orientation* within $\mathbb{R^2}$ (circular topology)

My first impulse was to use *scalar* but I'm not sure whether its meaning explicitly forbids the 2nd example above.

Comment: Would a "variable" that lies on a lemniscate be acceptable? What about an ordinary variable constrained to be rational? If not, then you probably want to say "a value constrained to a 1-dimensional domain" (i.e., the rather subtle notion of 1-manifold is the one you really want, and you should face facts and just use it).

Comment: @JohnHughes Those can be included or excluded, whichever allows for a word. I just need a generalization of Scalar that includes the 2 listed cases but excludes 2-manifolds.

Comment: It depends on the application domain, but I would be inclined to say something involving the phrase *one degree of freedom*.

Comment: @Rahul Indeed. I'm looking for a word to use throughout a document to avoid repeating that phrase endlessly. The meaning doesn't have to be unambiguous as I can provide a definition in the document. It just needs to be sufficiently descriptive to distinguish from vector-valued variables used in the same document.

Comment: One thought: use the word "parameter", and give a gloss on what it means when you first introduce it, something like "We'll use the word  **parameter** to indicate a variable representing a single degree of freedom, like the $x$-position of a point in the plane, or the amount of rotation of a shape in the plane, or a single coordinate of the velocity vector of some object." It's not idea, in the sense that you may not always write down parametric equations for the thing discussed, but it'll probably work OK.

Comment: A "scalar variable".

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Is that applicable to circular topology? Can direction in $\mathbb{R^2}$ be considered scalar?

Comment: A 1-DOF variable. // P.S. Won't you have a similar problem with the term *vector* applied to variables modeling direction ($\in \mathbb S^{n-1}$) or orientation ($\in {\rm SO}(n)$) in $n$ dimensions? Neither of those sets are vector spaces.